# Java: Copy strings from a file to another without losing the 'newline format'

Tags: java, string, copy, format

Sorry in advance if the title is misleading/wrong but this is the best I can do after a really long day spent practicing with Java. (my brain is melting)

I put this code togheter to read a file and copy it into another file, skipping the line/lines that begins with a given string (BeginOfTheLineToRemove). It actually works and remove the desired line, but, for some reason, it forgets about the \n (newline). Spacing and symbols are copied. I can't figure it out. I really hope someone will help. cheers from a java newb from italy ;)

```
public void Remover(String file, String BeginOfTheLineToRemove) {
    File StartingFile = new File(file);
    File EndingFile = new File(StartingFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(EndingFile));

    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.startsWith(LineToRemoveThatBeginWithThis)) {
            continue;
        }
        pw.write(line);
    }

    pw.close();
    br.close();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `pw.println` instead of `pw.write`. println adds new line character after it writes content.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `PrintWriter.write()` to write the lines - This does not by default write newline at the end. Use `println()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) will probably help you.

The BufferedReader.readLine() method does not read any line termination characters. So therefore your line will not contain any termination characters.

Answer (score 1):

[BufferedReader#readLine](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) documentation says:

> Returns: A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached

That is, the reader strips the line termination characters from your Strings, so you need to manually add them again:

```
// \n on Linux/Mac, \r\n on Windows
String lineSep = System.getProperty("line.separator"); 
pw.write(line);
pw.write(lineSep);
```

Answer (score 0):

BufferedReader.readLine() uses the newline to identify the end of the line, and the string that it returns does not contain this newline. The newline is a separator, so it is not considered part of the data.

To compensate for this, you can add a newline to your output, like so:

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if(line.startsWith(LineToRemoveThatBeginWithThis)) continue;
    pw.write(line);
    pw.println();
}
```

The extra call to PrintWriter.println() will print a newline after you write out your line of text.

Answer (score 0):

Outside the loop get the system's line seperator:

```
String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Then append that to the line you've read in:

```
pw.write(line+lineSeparator);
```